# fPIC compiling error: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, configure, fpic

I am running elementary OS 64-bit and have the source code for the following project on github:

https://github.com/pellegre/libcrafter

I however get the following error when trying to configure it via the `./configure` command:

[image]

After that I check the `config.log` file:

[image]

Anyone know why this could be? I've compiled with fPIC before without hassle.

Example from the configure file in the folder:

[image]

Update for Peter in comments:

[image]

Comment: Odd. Well the reason you're getting an error is because, for some reason, the `-` is being dropped and `g++` is trying to compile the non-existent file `fPIC`.

Comment: @DanielGibbs added an image example of the -fPIC of the configure file!

Comment: @DanielGibbs I'll also add that I am running 64-bit OS, could it be that?

Comment: I don't think that's where the `fPIC` is coming from, as `-shared` isn't shown the original output provided. Try updating your version of `autoconf`.

Comment: @KarlMorrison could it be that you somehow changed your `CC` or `CXX` or `AC_PROG_CXX` environment variables to `g++ fPIC` or something?

Comment: @PeterT Oooooh I think it could be that, I'll look and get back to you.

Comment: @PeterT Ok updated the thread with a picture of both env. var. I am guessing the CXX is incorrect?

Comment: @KarlMorrison well yeah, you should make that `g++ -fPIC` obviously, or just make it `g++` because I don't like baking flags into `CXX`. Just do `CXX=g++` or `CXX="g++ -fPIC"` in your terminal if you want to set it just for that session of the terminal. `export CXX=g++` should make that permanent

Comment: @KarlMorrison did you reconfigure (aka make autoconf regenerate the configure file)?

Comment: @PeterT I am noticing that everytime I set the env. var. it goes back to "CXX=g++ fPIC". Even when setting as sudo.

Comment: @KarlMorrison hm, have you tried the `export CXX=g++` ? I wouldn't think that it makes a difference but maybe your `.bashrc` gets read every time for some reason. Oh, and setting it as sudo, sets it for sudo only, since (as far as I know) every user usually has his own env-vars

Comment: @PeterT BOOM and you fixed it! I did forget to use export when setting the env. var., however doesn't explain why it was `CXX=g++ fPIC` to begin with, weird. Create an answer and I'll accept.