# gfortran: error: -fPIC -ffree-line-length-0: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, gnu, gfortran, fpic

I am running into the following compiler error:

```
[  0%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/orion.dir/source/main/helpers.F90.o
gfortran: error:  -fPIC  -ffree-line-length-0: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/orion.dir/build.make:326: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/orion.dir/source/main/helpers.F90.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/orion.dir/source/main/helpers.F90.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/orion.dir/build.make:342: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/orion.dir/source/main/helpers.F90.o.provides' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/orion.dir/source/main/helpers.F90.o.provides] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/orion.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/orion.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The makefile was generated using CMake using

```
ccmake ../
```

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have environment variables set for `FC,CC,CXX` to where `mpif90, mpicc, mpicxx` the MPI-wrapped gnu compilers are located, respectively.

I don't have issues compiling this code on other Linux and macOS machines, so I'm pretty sure the compile error is specific to something on the system I'm currently compiling in.

I couldn't find any `gfortran` -specific  posts on this. I did find a similar post in [fPIC compiling error: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107913/fpic-compiling-error-no-such-file-or-directory), but I don't think the issues identified there are what's causing my error.

Comment: might be useful to get the command used in the Makefile to compile. Have a go with `-n` to see what command is used at he place of the compilation.

Comment: Sorry it's taking me awhile to navigate this giant makefile where it defines a bunch of variables in different files. It looks like the flags that are being used are ```-O3   -cpp -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 -ffixed-line-length-none -ffree-line-length-none -fbacktrace -fstack-arrays -funroll-loops " -fPIC  -ffree-line-length-0"```

Comment: What do those double quotes (`"`) in the line with options? Where do they come from? Further I think `-ffree-line-length-none` and `-ffree-line-length-0` is a bit double (and error prone).

Comment: Make with `make VERBOSE=1` so we can see the failing commandline and post that instead.

Comment: Thanks all, but I reinstalled some other code (call it code1) that the code in the OP is linked to, and it appeared to have fixed the issue. code1 was previously compiled with gnu compilers, and I recompiled with mpi-wrapped gnu compilers and that fixed the issue. I have no idea why though.